Sort data by number in cell containing number sometimes followed by text
I'm working on a shopping list with aisle numbers in Google Sheets and the aisle numbers can be digits alone or digits followed by a letter.
For example 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6A, 8, 19B, etc
I want to sort by aisle number but Sheets will sort 6A after  19B.
For example, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 8,  19B, 6A, etc
How can I make it sort by aisle number correctly?

Assuming that aisle numbers are in column A1:A, insert a new column and put this formula in row 1 of the new column:
=arrayformula(
  iferror(
    text(regexextract(to_text(A1:A), "^\d+"), "0000") 
    & iferror(regexextract(to_text(A1:A), "^\d+(.+)")),  
    A1:A 
  ) 
)

Then use the new column as the sort key column.



Aisle
Sort key




1
0001


2
0002


3
0003


3
0003


4
0004


6A
0006A


8
0008


19B
0019B




Use SORTN and REGEXEXTRACT
=LET(list,FILTER(A:D,A:A<>""), 
   aisle,INDEX(list,,1),
   SORTN(list,9^4,1,
     REGEXEXTRACT(""&aisle, "\d*")*1,1,
     REGEXEXTRACT(""&aisle, "\d*(\w*)"),1))


Put your list range in list, I used columns A:D in my example. It uses FILTER to get rid of any empty rows.
aisle is the first column of list
Lastly your range is sorted using SORTN by aisle number, followed by the aisle letter. REGEXEXTRACT is used to return the numbers and letters.

